# how to use a picture as coordinate system?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a question plotting with R: I have x-y-coordinates that are based on pixels (a 658px x 402px jpg picture). I want to plot the x-y-Coordinates WITH the picture (a map) as a background.

I tried this, but as it turns out there is something wrong; the points should be in the north sea (all of them)

```
d <- read.csv("~/Dropbox/IMITATION3/d.csv", sep=";")

library(ggplot2)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
ima <- readJPEG("~/Dropbox/IMITATION3/image.jpg")

ggplot(d, aes(IM02_cx, IM02_cy)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(ima, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                    -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  stat_bin2d(bins = 55) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0,0))
```

Here is the image:

[image: 1]

CSV:

```
CASE;IM02_cx;IM02_cy
412;191;75
127;222;74
459;220;73
80;138;72
86;225;72
458;156;71
71;86;69
289;219;69
291;219;68
77;221;68
338;199;67
495;200;67
371;138;66
197;227;66
64;134;65
105;170;65
124;196;65
237;171;64
350;213;64
63;92;63
305;106;63
286;139;63
99;199;63
353;201;63
362;198;62
452;168;60
479;204;60
65;209;60
330;214;60
132;101;59
162;184;59
93;182;58
249;209;58
49;117;57
106;172;57
83;150;56
282;168;56
234;190;56
492;165;55
40;181;55
448;195;55
262;184;54
199;165;53
47;92;52
109;143;52
107;147;52
97;208;51
467;145;50
98;169;50
451;169;49
480;117;48
414;96;47
424;122;47
466;143;47
514;170;47
465;133;45
176;172;45
69;183;45
417;109;44
220;140;44
160;96;43
172;128;43
48;132;43
344;156;43
490;163;43
396;182;43
374;163;41
327;172;41
128;173;41
408;82;40
53;147;40
409;158;40
225;71;38
402;70;37
469;149;34
284;99;32
455;163;32
149;174;21
```

PS: I don't know why but I had to reverse my y-scale to get the points (basiclly) at the right angle...–

Comment: we don't have your images or data, so it's unlikely we can help much.

Comment: sorry, couln't upload a picture, so here:
Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cka0lq5fdrvvk9b/d.csv?dl=0  and Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7tlgi6o3wq8si5/image.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also add `+ xlim(c(0, ncol(ima)))` and `+ ylim(nrow(ima), 0)` to your existing plot.

Comment: totally cool. good soln! I tend to go overboard with the mapping ones.

Answer (score 6):

You are making the coordinate reference system your image, so you have to deal with the "projection" manually. You can also use `ggimage` from the `ggmap` package. The following assumes your data is in `dat`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)

ima <- readJPEG("image.jpg")

gg <- ggimage(ima)
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=IM02_cx, y=nrow(ima)-IM02_cy))
gg
```

[image]